# How to solve limit whose function uses another function as a parameter?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

I am given the limit bellow. How do I solve this problem? I am thrown off by the f(f(x)). I believe the answer is -2 but am not sure and would like an explanation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For $x$ "close" to $-3$ we *always* have $f(x) = 2$. And $f(f(x)) = f(2) = -1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \le -2$ then $f(x) = 2$.  And $f(2) = -1$.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ if $\delta = 1$ then $|x-(-3)| < \delta \implies -4 < x < -2\implies f(x) = 2 \implies f(f(x)) =-1$ and $|f(f(x)) - (-1)| = |f(2) - (-1)| = |(-1)-(-1)| = 0 < \epsilon $.

And that is the very definition of $\lim\limits_{x\to -3} f(f(x)) = -1$.

Comment: $\text{misplaced \$ after \\implies}$